# uninstall 12.10

Tags: 12.10, uninstall

I am newbie. I upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10 using "sudo do-release-upgrade -d". Now, I am not able to get the system to boot up.  Is there a way of reversing this and re-installing 12.04?  Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't revert to 12.04 if you haven't made a backup.

**You have two options:**

1. Tell us what error message you get, so we can troubleshoot the issue and get 12.10 into a working state.
2. Reinstall 12.04 from live media.

Comment: When I switch on, the screen is blank, and if I try recovery mode, it asks me for login and pw and upon entering, i don't get the regular login screen.  Can you help?

Comment: I have a bootable USB with 12.04.  I don't mind re-installing.  Could you direct me on how to install it?

Comment: Did you install proprietary graphics drivers? Those might be the culprit, but I'm not shure. I would suggest running sudo `apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` that should update and install packages and might show if some packages were not properly installed. Running `sudo update-initramfs -u` may also help in case of a broken initrd.img. At last you could try to boot the old 12.04 kernel from Grub menu, that may still be good.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried sudo apt-get update. Result: "could not resolve in.archive.ubuntu.com and others like "failed to fetch..." Finally, "some index files failed to download. They have been ignored,or old ones used instead"

Comment: Me not knowing much of the commands, i do not want to get in further risk. Could you help me in re-installing 12.04.  I am happy with this version.  I have a bootable USB with v.12.04

Comment: Re-installation is no different from normal installation.